# Dynamic type in Generics

Tags: c#, generics

I'm currently looking into C# Generics, and I have a few questions.

1) In the following code, will the comparison of the type of T in "Test" slow down the program? In other languages this is handled on compile time, but I don't know about C#.

2) Since sizeof apparently won't work, I have to use System.Runtime.InteropServices.Marshal.SizeOf. Is this correct?

3) I haven't seen code like this in C# yet, is there anything wrong about it, or is it perfectly fine what I'm doing here? In the end the method in this example would take a handful of types, and throw and exception if it can't handle it. Some types would be handled independently, others like short/int/long would be handled together, depending on their size.

```
using System;

namespace ConsoleApplication1
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            Test<int>();
            Test<long>();
            Test<string>();
            Console.ReadLine();
        }

        static void Test<T>()
        {
            Type type = typeof(T);

            if (type == typeof(int) || type == typeof(long))
            {
                Console.WriteLine("int");
                Console.WriteLine(System.Runtime.InteropServices.Marshal.SizeOf(type).ToString());
            }
            else if (type == typeof(string))
            {
                Console.WriteLine("string");
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: 1) you can run it with a timer and check. 2) have you tried sizeof? It works fine for me. 3) It is fine the way you have it (just add a last elseif at the end for the exception). Though I would do it with a switch(). Unlike in C++ the switch statement can compare more then int/enums.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, the type comparison slows it down, not that such an operation will significantly affect anything done only once. If you're doing this in a tight loop somewhere... consider *not* doing it. This is because it creates a `Type` object and compares those `Type` objects - it's not a compile-time check.

Yes, `Marshal.SizeOf` is correct<sup>1</sup>. I don't know what C#'s `sizeof` does, though, because I'm a VB.NET person.

As for not seeing this type of code much in C#, that's probably because it's not a case that people often come across. **And also, instead of doing what you're doing, you should be offering method *overloads* for each type; cleaner, and the error is at compile-time, not runtime.**

<sub><sup>1</sup> You're just printing it out, it's correct to print it out. I don't know what the goal of all this is, though.</sub>

Comment: `sizeof(Type)` returns the size of a certain type which seems to be exactly what OP wants. I have no idea why it didn't work for him. In any case `Marshal.SizeOf` is the `OO` way of doing it (well `.NET` style `OO`) *note*: I am a C# (and Java) person 8D

Comment: `sizeof(Type)` returns the size of the managed struct. `Marshal.SizeOf()` returns the size of the unmanaged struct that results after marshaling. The two are not always the same size. (e.g. `sizeof(char)=2` but `Marshal.SizeOf(typeof(char))=1`)

Answer (score 5):

1) It will be done at runtime, not compile-time.  This isn't C++ templates.  That said, it's a pretty fast operation.

3) If there are a fixed number of types that you need to support your better off using method overloading than generics.

Have `Test(int input)`,`Test(string input)`, and so on for each type you need to support.  You can have a generic method in addition to those if there is a "general case" to support for everything else.